# In CMake how to include header files of the project

Tags: c++, cmake

In a C++ project, I would like to set the header files as descendants of the project's source directory, without use of UNIX directory shortcuts `.` or `..`. Im not sure how to configure cmake to work with that.

I have the directory structure:

```
Root
|-include
| |- foo.h
|-src
| | foo.cpp
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

put into root\CMakeList.txt:

```
project(root)
include_directories(${root_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
...
```

you can use root_SOURCE_DIR everywhere in sub projects.

for more information consider to visit http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables#Variables_not_listed_here

Comment: Do forward slashes (${root_SOURCE_DIR}/include) work on windows?

Answer (score 14):

Use `include_directories( include )` for CMakeLists.txt in Root folder. Or `include_directories( ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include )` from any subfolder.