# including files from a parallel directory structure

Tags: c++, cmake, include-path

Not-quite duplicate: [CMake include path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15392561/cmake-include-path)

I originally had a directory structure like this:

```
root
    src
        foodir
            foo.cpp
            foo.h
```

Header files were then moved into their own, parallel directories:

```
root
    src
        foodir
            foo.cpp
    include
        foodir
            foo.h
```

The problem is.. where foo.cpp used to just use `#include "foo.h"`, it now has to use `#include "foodir/foo.h"` (compiled with `-Iinclude`).

Ok, so it is not a real "problem," but it would be best if I could retain the "foo.h" instead of "foodir/foo.h" (lots of files). Is there any way, with cmake, to have the compiler look in the *corresponding* subdirectory of `include/`?

Answer (score 2):

To add `include/foodir` to the list of compiler search paths, just use [`include_directories`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3ainclude_directories).  Assuming your top-level CMakeLists.txt is in "root":

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/foodir)
```

Comment: ...or, if you are already on CMake 2.8.11 or newer, use the more powerful [`target_include_directories`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:target_include_directories) instead.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to pass a suitable `-I<dir>/foobar` argument. For example `-Iinclude/foobar` may work. When using `make` you'd conventionally add the option to `CPPFLAGS` (what is realky used depends on the project specific rules, of course).