# CMAKE: Library Missing Header File

Tags: c++, linker, cmake, header-files

I have a subdirectory that creates a shared library that builds into a folder off my root project. I link it in my cmake file without any problems. However, the compiler can't find the header files no matter how I reconfigure it.

The folder structure is similar to :

**Root**

- build

  - lib
- src

  - library
- test

  - library_test

Essentially I want to link the library that compiles to the lib folder to link to its test. However, no matter how I configure the CMakelists, it can't find the header file for the library during compilation. However, there are no errors during the cmake process.
The actual error message reads as follows:

> fatal error: 'file.h' file not found

My post recent attempt:

```
find_library(LESSIONS_LIBS chp_two PATHS {CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/build/lib/)
add_library(test_chptwo SHARED ${TEST})
target_link_libraries(test_chptwo gtest LESSIONS_LIBS)
```

Any ideas?

---

## Edit One

Here are my updated CMakelists:

The library CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7.0)

#Project Name
project (chp_two)

#Build Problem Sets as Library
#Header Files 
include_directories(include ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc/)
#Source files
set(LIB random_queue.cpp ${include})
add_library(chp_two SHARED ${LIB})
```

The Test CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7.0)

#Project Name
project(TESTING)

#Setting Test sources
set(TEST test_random_queue.cpp)

#Search for libraries
find_library(LESSIONS_LIBS chp_two PATHS {CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/build/lib/)

enable_testing()

#turn test into a library
add_library(test_chptwo SHARED ${TEST})

target_link_libraries(test_chptwo gtest LESSIONS_LIBS)
```

Comment: Which **project** cause the error: one for the *library*, or one for the *test*? Add this information into the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake include path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15392561/cmake-include-path)

Comment: Have you solved this?

Comment: @Rexcirus no, I was unable to figure it out.

Comment: You should use target_include_directories instead.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to know for sure without your cmake file. However, would you by any chance be missing the include_directories call?  This call will set the path to your .h files for compilation.

```
include_directories (path_to_my_headers)
```

Below is a CMAKE example of what I am referring to in the comments. Same concept applies to both libs/exe more or less anyway.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7.0)
# 
project (MyProj)
#
include_directories (.)
include_directories (path_to_a_dir_with_files_I_need)
include_directories (path_to_another_dir_with_files_I_need)

#
file (GLOB HEADERS *.h)
file (GLOB SOURCES *.cpp)

# Finish with your CXX flags, add_executable, target_link_libraries, install, etc
```

Comment: I did that in the library's CMakelist. Must I reinclude the header for the library in every file that I link to it?

Comment: Your shared lib has functions that are defined in the header. Linking to lib is not enough since that only help after compilation. Include the headers in the calling app so that it knows the functions from lib its needs to eventually call.

Comment: What is the best way to handle this with cmake and potentially a larger project?

Comment: With cmake its not a big deal. One time setup.

Comment: Full CMakeLists.txt would help. If you have multiple CMakeLists.txt, provide all of them.

Comment: @ivan_onys I just add two of my CMakelists

Comment: @gsilva2016 I am still confused by how to do what you are saying. Like should I copy all the header files to central place so that they are easily accessible? I know it is probably a stupid question but please indulge me.

Comment: @Aaron I believe you can use `include_directories()` on the 'top' level of hierarchy. In CMakeLists.txt **above** src:

`include_directories(${MY_STUFF})

add_subdirectory(src)

add_subdirectory(test)`

If this does not help, I guess, you have to copy `include_directories()` every time

Comment: @Aaron thanks for the including the CMake files. I am assuming the Test/library_test  is the calling app.  Since your calling app needs the header to your lib you need to add "include_directories (path_to_my_libs_header_directory)" to Test CMakeLists. You can use ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} or ${PROJ_DIR} to you help out.

Comment: @Aaron, also your libs CMakeLists you only need to call include_directories for the headers you need for that lib.  Be sure the path is correct when you use it e.g. clean up include_directories(include ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc/)

Comment: I've also found it easier to include the sources and headers using file (GLOB HEADERS *.h)
file (GLOB SOURCES *.cpp) instead of setting each file manually.